# How to call the existing object in python

Tags: python, class

I have this kind of code.

```
class typeOne(self, obj):
  ....
  def run():
    # I want to call the funct() from typeTwo


class typeTwo(self, obj2):
  ...
  def funct():
    ...

class typePlayer(self, obj3):
  ...
  tT = typeTwo()
  ...
  tT.funct()
    .....
```

I want to reference the typeTwo class from typeOne class that has been called in the typePlayer.

I tried this one.

```
class typeOne:
  ....
  mytT = typeTwo() # another probs here is that how can I get the 'obj2'?
  def run():
     mytT.funct()
```

but it creates new typeTwo() class and I don't need it, I just only want to call the existing typeTwo() class and not to create one, the typeTwo() class that has been executed by typePlayer() Class.

does anyone has an idea about this?

Comment: You seem to be a little confused about the distinction between classes and instances.

Comment: This is either about inclusion, inheritance, or static methods, but I'm not sure which

Comment: Hi Guys, I just only want to call the mytT.func() from typeTwo class that has been called by the typePlayer... do I make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If one class needs access to a particular instance of another class, the usual solution is to pass the needed instance to to the first class when instantiating it. For example:

```
class TypeOne(object):

  def __init__(self, myt2=None):
     self.myt2 = myt2 or TypeTwo()  # create instance if none given 

  def run():
     self.myt2.funct()
```

Then, something like this to instantiate both:

```
myt2 = TypeTwo()
myt1 = TypeOne(myt2)
```

Of course, since `TypeOne` is written to create a `TypeTwo` instance if none is passed in, you can also do it the other way around, letting `TypeOne` create the `TypeTwo` instance and then grabbing that out of the `TypeOne` instance:

```
myt1 = TypeOne()   # creates its own TypeTwo instance
myt2 = myt1.myt2   # retrieves that instance for outside use
```

Comment: thanks kindall, Im so confused about classes and instances... do u have any example if the classes has a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want funct() in TypeTwo to be class static:

```
class TypeTwo(object):
  ...
  @staticmethod
  def funct(x):
    ...

class TypeOne(object):
  ....
  def run():
    TypeTwo.funct(x)
```